# Script closing when a button is pushed

Tags: vbscript

I am programming in VBScript and I just got the hang of the `ReturnValue = MsgBox("Content", 36, "Title")`, and I want my code to close when you press the *yes* button, but open an application when you press the *no* button.

Here's the code so far:

```
ReturnValue = MsgBox("Content", 36, "Title")
If ReturnValue = 7 Then
  Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WSHShell.run "open this.exe"
End If

If ReturnValue = 6 Then
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Remove `open`..directly write exe name in code `WSHShell.run "this.exe"`..

Comment: Can you please explain the problem? It appears to work exactly as you have it...

Comment: @Susilo It's pretty obvious that "open this.exe" is a placeholder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script seems to work fine as is.  Here it is with minor changes to make the functionality more obvious:

```
ReturnValue = MsgBox("Click yes to exit." + vbCrlf + "Click no to open Notepad.", 36, "Exit Script?")
If ReturnValue = 7 Then
   Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   WSHShell.run "notepad.exe"
End If

If ReturnValue = 6 Then
    MsgBox "Script is now exiting"
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

If you are experiencing other behavior, please let us know what it is.

Here is the full documentation for the `MsgBox` command: http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html